# Boundary condition for dielectric to dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism

Now the tangential component of the electric field at the boundary is continuous, but the normal component of the electric field is said to be discontinuous. What is the meaning of discontinuous in this case? Does it mean that at a particular point on the boundary , the normal component of the electric field is not defined?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, by "discontinuous" it means that it has a different value (in V/M) on one side of the boundary than it does on the other, as in a step function.

Comment: If you want to know more about the fundamental physics of the situation, I'll migrate your question to Physics.SE. If you're more interested in the EE applications of it, it can stay here.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something has to modify the normal component of the normal part of the wave. The discontinuous definition comes from the material. The wave propagates until it sees material, this material looks like a discontinuity to the wave (a step function in material properties if you think about it).

In addition the normal component is discontinuous if there is a surface charge density, if there is no surface charge then there is no discontinuity:

[image]
Source: http://www.antenna-theory.com/tutorial/electromagnetics/electric-field-boundary-conditions.php